# How I can set an element in the bottom of a layout when the layout has the property android: layout_height = "wrap_content"?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, imageview

I have a layout that is dynamically enlarged, and I have a imageview I would like to always stay stuck at the bottom of the layout. My code is as follows

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bot" 
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/descripcion"
        android:layout_width="170dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/la_descripcion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dfsasdfasfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdjfas sdf sadf  sadf trh h t  5454  dsdfjsdf sdfsdfhk  sdf f sdf hk sdf "
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_tag"
        android:layout_width="5.84mm"
        android:layout_height="4.21mm"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" 
        android:background="@drawable/agotado"

        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

If the textview "la_descripción" was longer, the "LinearLayout" would enlarge the image but would stay fixed and not in the bottom

Comment: any issue using relative layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_tag"
    android:layout_width="5.84mm"
    android:layout_height="4.21mm"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" 
    android:background="@drawable/agotado"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
```

That should do it if you want to stick to LinearLayout, otherwise, if you switch to RelativeLayout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_tag"
    android:layout_width="5.84mm"
    android:layout_height="4.21mm"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" 
    android:background="@drawable/agotado"
    android:alignParentBottom="true"
    />
```

Comment: android:layout_gravity="bottom"  :D work ^u^. Gracias :D

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant, yes. Glad it helped.